# pm2 cannot start express application

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

I wrote a simple Express application. It ran correctly with "npm start". The scripts in package.json is this:

```
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
  "start": "src/bin/www.js"
}
```

But I couldn't execute it like this:

```
pm2 start ./src/bin/www.js
```

I checked pm2.log. It shown "had too many unstable restarts(16)".

Then ran it with pm2-dev:

```
pm2-dev start ./src/bin/www.js
```

Reported the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
```

Pm2 can't work well with import/export? The node version is 14.16.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure if you have following two points:

1. Node version >= 14. It only works with latest version of node.
2. Make sure your package.json includes a line for "type": "module", Without this line node assumes you want to use Common JS modules rather than ESM.

If both are true and it's still not working then you might be victim of following github issue

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4540

For now you can try running it with babel!

Comment: It does not work. Node version is 14.16.0 and "type": "module". The Express app can run with "npm run start", only not work for pm2.

Comment: @Henry True, I believe there is this on going issue in github, it has quite recent comments too 
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/4540

Comment: Thank you! Yes. Then I use Babel to build and run it successfully.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my answer and add the github link to it then! also the fact that you using babel is the answer for now